# How to handle the storm of 10.04-related questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been seeing a lot of questions regarding 10.04 and how it recently broke after an update. Does anyone know the technical background why these users are experiencing similar problems? What's the best course of action here? Flag as duplicate or off-topic/EOL? Should you even try to answer such questions?

Just a few examples I came across the last few *minutes*:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/479306/latest-update-to-10-04-problem?newreg=1c9cb7f1e9fa4cff84a6433075cd19a2

https://askubuntu.com/questions/480596/problem-with-the-latest-update-of-ubuntu-10-04#comment639465_480596

https://askubuntu.com/questions/480857/why-does-my-system-freeze-right-click

**EDIT**: bonus question: [How to install the latest Octave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138832/installing-the-latest-octave-3-6-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts?rq=1) - should you leave a comment in a question like that 
telling the user that they should upgrade to a newer release?

**EDIT 2**: I understand that 10.04 Server is not EOL, these questions are about Firefox, VLC and other applications that clearly indicate that these are **10.04 Desktops**.

Comment: by the way, 10.04 is not EoL, well kinda. The desktop version is EoL while the server version is still under maintenance. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: @Dan these questions are all desktop questions. (Firefox, VLC, etc.)

Comment: The three questions you link should be bug reports, not questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10.04 is NOT totally EOL yet (server version ends april 2015). So make sure the topic is not about the server version.

All new dekstop related questions about 10.04 are off topic.

===

Bonus: yes of course. Even if you do not flag the topic (for instance when the release itself does not really seem to matter) leave a comment that they should update to a newer version.

===

2 of the 3 flagged; 3rd one was already flagged and closed.

Comment: Actually only certain package are supported, is not like I install the server version and then start installing desktop applications.